# where do i call Random.Range( )

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The following code throws an error:

> UnityException: Range is not allowed to be called from a MonoBehaviour constructor (or instance field initializer), call it in Awake or Start instead.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Cube : MonoBehaviour
{
    public MeshRenderer Renderer;

    private float speed = Random.Range(10f, 30f);

    void Start()
    {
        transform.Rotate(speed* Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    }
       
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Random.ColorHSV(0f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 0.5f, 1f, 0.5f, 1f); 
        }
    }
}
```

So I edited it by calling the Range method in start

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Cube : MonoBehaviour
{
    public MeshRenderer Renderer;

    void Start()
    {
        private float speed = Random.Range(10f, 30f);
        transform.Rotate(speed* Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        { 
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Random.ColorHSV(0f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 0.5f, 1f, 0.5f, 1f); 
        }
    }
}
```

However, I got a bunch of errors, such as error `CS1513`, `CS1519`, `CS8124` etc.

I'm sorry if this sounds really dumb, and I've been trying to fix this by calling Range in `Awake()` or googling for similar situations online, but nothing seems to be working.

To summarize:

1. Where do I call `Random.Range()` in my code?
2. Why does calling it in `Start()` result in a variety of syntax errors, such as `} expected` when I already typed `}`?

Comment: On a local variable, you cannot specify "private". Just remove that

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Where do I call `Random.Range()` in my code?

As Unity tells you within a class derived from `MonoBehaviour` it can't be done at field initialization time (which happens before the constructor is executed). The reason is most probably mainly because this instance created by the underlying `c++` backend entity component system and accessing the `UnityEngine.Random` class from there or in general from other threads is unreliable (see [`UnityEngine.Random`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.html))

→ Unity already tells you exactly what to do though

> call it in `Awake` or `Start` instead

you have to assign the value within one of the event message methods `Awake`, `Start`, etc.

> 2. Why does calling it in `Start()` result in a variety of syntax errors, such as `} expected` when I already typed `}`?

Because a local variable within a method can not have any access modifiers and you have `private` there. So the compiler expects you to first close the `Start` method with a `}` before using the keyword `private`. The rest are just follow up compiler errors.

---

You want to keep the field declaration at class level and then assign it in `Start`

```
private float speed;

private void Start ()
{
    speed = Random.Range(10f, 30f);
}
```

---

Then you also most probably don't want to rotate only once in `Start` but rather move it into `Update` in order to get a continous rotation.

```
private void Update ()
{
    transform.Rotate(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    
    ...
}
```

---

Finally (this is more a general side note) you should change the field type and rather cache

```
// Already assign vis the Inspector if possible
public Renderer renderer;

private void Awake ()
{
    // Get ONCE as fallback
    if(!renderer) renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
}
```

and then reuse that reference

```
private void Update ()
{
    ...

    // it is also preferred to use KeyCode instead of strings
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        renderer.material.color = Random.ColorHSV(0f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 0.5f, 1f, 0.5f, 1f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unity works weirdly on the backend. You'll need to declare `private float speed;` like in the first snippet. Then in the start/awake method call `speed = Random.Range(10f, 30f);`

```
public class Cube : MonoBehaviour
{
    public MeshRenderer Renderer;

    private float speed;
    void Start()
    {
        speed = Random.Range(10f, 30f);
        transform.Rotate(speed* Time.deltaTime, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    }
       
   
    void Update()
    {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
        {GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Random.ColorHSV(0f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 0.5f, 1f, 0.5f, 1f); }
        
    }
}
```